# concurrent queries with a single connection in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, concurrency, pyodbc

i've got a python 3.8 script that uses the libraries pyobdc and concurrent.futures to query on a DB.

**NB i want to clerify that i know i can have more than one connection and i know for sure that it's happening. what i cannot understand is where my bottleneck is**

the structure is: I have one script (call it queries) that is imported in the second script (call it main) as a module.
queries is a collection of functions, all with the same structure:

```
def getquery1():
    connection = pyobdbc.connect('connection string')
    query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
    with connection:
        result_dataset = pd.read_sql(con=connection,sql=query)
    connection.close()
    return result_dataset
```

in main I import that file as a module.
then i recall all the data as:

```
import queries
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pyodbc

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
futureQuery1 = executor.submit(queries.getquery1)   
futureQuery2 = executor.submit(queries.getquery2)
futureQuery3 = executor.submit(queries.getquery3)
result1 = futureQuery1.result()
result2 = futureQuery2.result()
result3 = futureQuery3.result()
```

the infrastructure is: i have this script that runs on a linux machine and connects to a microsoft SQL. the driver used is FreeTDS
on SQL i got this parameters:

```
print(connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_MAX_DRIVER_CONNECTIONS)) --> 0 (unlimited connections)
print(connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_MAX_CONCURRENT_ACTIVITIES)) --> 1
print(connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_MAX_ASYNC_CONCURRENT_STATEMENTS)) --> 1
```

the thing is:

if query1 and query 2 are on the same connection, those two queries are executed at the same time? or query2 must wait the end of query1?

and if query3 connect to another database can that query be executed at the same time of the first two?

where i can find those parameters?

i'm usually in the case where the main script runs at the same time from two different machines that connects to the same docker

USEFULL LINKS:

- FreeTDS https://www.freetds.org/docs.html
- concurrent.futures https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html
- sql get info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This is the wrong way to do things. Firstly, if you want multiple queries simultaneously, you must use two connections. Secondly, running two queries simultaneously is probably not going to help you much, as generally databases are IO constrained, not CPU constrained, and SQL Server can parallelize queries anyway.

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately the request is to have two calls on main that runs at the same time. What's the best practice you suggest? to open two connections for queries 1 and 2? what's your suggestion?

Comment: Then use two different connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a protocol to allow a single connection to have multiple concurrent queries running at the same time.  It's called [Multiple Active Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15), and I have no idea if FreeTDS uses it, but the [Microsoft ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15) can.

However the execution of mutliple queries on a single connection is *interleaved* not concurrent.  If you want two queries to actually execute at the same time, use two connections.