running concurrent query in SQL Server using single connection
I'm trying to run concurrent queries using single connection on Azure SQL Server using aioodbc client.
But i get this error
'HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!'

If i run the functions one by one then its works fine.
Sample code:
output1, output2 = await asyncio.gather(
                        execute_fn1(cur, sql1),
                        execute_fn2(cur, sql2)
                    )

Does running parallel queries using single connection works on ODBC?

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499643/concurrent-queries-with-a-single-connection-in-pyodbc    (My) Conclusion: ODBC does not support parallel queries using a single connection.

@Luuk thanks for the quick response. Appreciated.
